# Perform Task Just Before Windows Lockout

Tags: windows

I'm wondering if there is a way to intercept that a Windows session is about to be locked and essentially provide a pop-up just before.  We've got an intranet punch in/out facility, and many people forget to punch in or out before leaving for lunch or for the day. Essentially I'm looking for a way to give the users the option to log out when they lock their machines.

I am also completely open to the possibility that this may not be possible due to security concerns, but I wanted to see what the community's take on it was anyway.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but the [Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents_events.aspx) class might have what you want.

Specifically, you may want to try the [SessionSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch.aspx) event. According to this bytes.com post, it should work:

[Handle the Windows Lock Desktop event/message?](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/445133-handle-windows-lock-desktop-event-message)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adam.  From what I've found, the only similar event is the session ending event, which unfortunately is not triggered by a session lock.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Remote Desktop Services API [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841.aspx) to get lock notifications, but there doesn't appear to be any way to override the lock.